# Reference type with partially qualified namespace

Tags: java, types

Is it possible to reference Java types with a partially qualified name? If so, how?

The scenario: I frequently find myself with a data class (e.g. `Activity`) which needs a view. My standard practice has been to name this class `ActivityView`, which works, but this view class invariably ends up in a `tld.organization.project.views` namespace, where the "View" suffix is entirely redundant.

I'd like to remove "View" suffix (so the types would be `tld.organization.project.Activity` and `tld.organization.project.views.Activity`), but this means I must use the namespace to qualify the types when I reference them in the same class. Using the namespace to qualify type references is not a bad thing in and of itself, but repeating the fully qualified name of either type is repetitious and difficult to read.

Referencing a *partially* qualified type (something like `~.Activity` or `~.views.Activity`) would remove that cruft. Some kind of type aliasing would answer, but it appears Java doesn't support such functionality. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Besides `import tld.organization.project.views.*`?

Comment: I don't think importing the type is helpful in this case, because the short names of the type are the same. I'll update the question to clarify that.

Comment: They're called 'package names' not namespaces.

Comment: Short answer: Nope.  No alternatives.

Comment: @JimGarrison "namespace" seemed like a more appropriate term for the issue at hand, which was all about names. See also (pulled from a quick Google search) http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch02_11.htm and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace_(computer_science)#Java

Comment: Java feels like jogging with a piece of wood hanging on your neck . Even in C you have more flexibility and expression power. 
I am generating some classes with Jaxb - you'll get an ObjectFactory in each package. Now call all of them with the full package name and you'll write the best spaghetti code ever.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't do that with packages in Java. The closest you could get would be to organize things into nested hierarchies of classes instead of packages. Between that and strategic static importing, you could get the desired effect, though it would be a terribly messy solution. For example:

```
package tld.organization.project;
public class Activity {}
```

and:

```
package tld.organization.project;
public class Views {
    public static class Activity {}
}
```

which can then be referred to as:

```
public void whatever() {
    Activity a = new Activity();
    Views.Activity a2 = new Views.Activity();
}
```

I'd suggest that the problems you're having with names may be pointing to a design problem that needs to be sorted out.

P.S. If I ever had to work on a project that organized classes so, I might have to shoot myself.

P.P.S. Actually, I'd probably try to shoot you first.

Comment: Upvote for frank postscripts. ;) I'm having trouble seeing the design problems of the proposed structure, though. It's a fairly straightforward application of the MVC design pattern. I was under the impression that separation of concerns (data model and data view in this case) was almost universally considered *good* design practice...

Comment: Separation comes in many flavors. Given the range of interpretations of "MVC", I don't want to assume I know what you mean by "data" vs "view" classes, but I see an indicator in your package names of a practice I've never agreed with: packaging classes based on the "layer" of the application they live in. I.e., having a "dao" package with UserDao, AccountDao, ..., and a "view" package with UserView, AccountView, ... My firm opinion is that it's much more understandable and less prone to package tangle to have a "user" and "account" package instead, each containing the relevant classes.

Comment: Interesting. I can see the advantages of your favored approach, but I'm not sure it solves my original problem: any time two functional units interact (say the "user" DAO needs to interact with the "account" DAO), we have the same problem of identical unqualified names. Also, it seems liked you'd want to be fairly sure no new "layers" are likely to be needed, since adding a new class to each package for the new "layer" would be fairly laborious.

Answer (score -2):

Are you trying to say that you dont want to write:

```
tld.organization.project.views.ActivityView
```

every time you use `ActivityView` ?

Use [import](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/language/10basics/import.html)

eg.  Instead of using fully qualified name of the class `JOptionPane` like this:

```
class ImportTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hi");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Import the class in the beginning like this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  // Make a single class visible.

class ImportTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hi");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Now you can directly use JOptionPane in your class.

Comment: He wants to *partially* qualify the name, i.e. `views.Activity` instead of `Activity` or `tld.blablabla.views.Activity`.`

Comment: Works because `JOptionPane` is a class, but the idea is to be able to do something similar with a package.